# How to write a template function that handle do catch

Tags: swift

I want to write a template function that handle do catch. It may look like this

```
func handleMethod(methodNeedToHandle) -> result: notSureType{
    var result
    do {
        let response = try handleMethod
        result = response
        return result
    } catch let error as someObjectError{
        result = error
        return result
    }  
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
let catchResult = handleMethod(method(x: something, y: something))
```

Thank you guys help me a lot, I get working code below

```
func handleDoTryCatch<T>(closure:() throws -> T) -> Any {
    do {
        let result = try closure()
        return result
    } catch let error {
        return error
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just simply use the `do/try/catch` without a separate method? What is the use of creating this function?

Comment: @George_E I am executing function test, so I need to verify many functions that need to use do/try/catch, so I think I need to write a template function to make my code is can re-useable

Comment: So you want to input a function, `do/try/catch`, then return the function output if it succeeds and return the error if it doesn't?

Comment: @George_E Exactly, thank you for make clear my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generic function that takes a closure and returns a tuple.

Something like:

```
func handle<T>(closure:() throws -> T) -> (T?, Error?) {
    do {
        let result = try closure()
        return (result, nil)
    } catch let error {
        return (nil, error)
    }
}
```

This will define a function that takes a closure that calls the method that can throw. It the returns a tuple with the expected return type and something that conforms to the Error protocol.

You would use it like this:

```
let result: (Void?, Error?) = handle { try someFunc() }
let result2: (Int?, Error?) = handle { try someOtherFunc(2) }
```

someFunc and someOtherFunc are just examples and their signatures would be:

```
func someFunc() throws {}
func someOtherFunc(_ param: Int) throws -> Int {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could get to what you probably want is the following:
(Swift Playground code:)

```
func handleMethod(_ f: @autoclosure () throws -> Void) -> Error? {
    do {
        try f()
    } catch let err {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

enum HelloError: Error {
    case tooShort
}

func hello(_ what: String) throws {
    guard what.count > 0 else { throw HelloError.tooShort }
    print ("Hello \(what)!")
}

// use like this:
// let err = handleMethod(try hello("World")) // err == nil
// let err = handleMethod(try hello(""))      // err == HelloError.tooShort
// 

print ("* hello(\"World\") -> \(String(describing: handleMethod(try hello("World"))))")
print ("* hello(\"\") -> \(String(describing: handleMethod(try hello(""))))")
```

This will produce the following output:

```
Hello World!
* hello("World") -> nil
* hello("") -> Optional(__lldb_expr_3.HelloError.tooShort)
```

Consider just using do/catch as George_E recommends. It's a good advice. But if you need this function, than this snipped hopefully gives you a starting point.

Comment: I tried and use let err = handleMethod(try hello("World")) but Xcode return error "Call can throw but is not marked with 'try'"

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I managed to come up with:

```
// Your error cases
enum Errors: Error {
    case someErrorCase
}


// Function to test another function
func doTryCatch<T>(for function: () throws -> T) {
    do {
        let returnValue = try function()
        print("Success! The return value is \(returnValue)")
    } catch {
        print("Error! The error reason was \"\(String(describing: error))\"")
    }
}


// Function to test
func failingFunction() throws -> Int {
    throw Errors.someErrorCase // <-- Comment this to not recieve an error (for testing)
    return 5 // Will return 5 if the error is not thrown

    // Failure: Error! The error reason was "someErrorCase"
    // Success: Success! The return value is 5
}


// Perform the test
doTryCatch(for: failingFunction) // <-- Very easy to test, no closures to write!
```

Hope this helps with your debugging! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I still stuck, your code can work because failingFunction is define: func failingFunction() throws -> Int, but if I need to execute with some functions that I don't know about its params and return value. Example: func anotherFailingFunction(x: Int, y: String , bla bla) -> someTypeNotsure ?

Comment: @LươngĐạiVệ I have been trying for a while, and don't think this is possible in Swift, sorry

Comment: @LươngĐạiVệ in my suggestion below this is possible. The actual function signature doesn't matter and the function can have an arbitrary number of arguments. That's what the `@autoclosure` is for.

Comment: @Lutz I have seen your solution but I did not try it, I will now